# Alter column charset and collation MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server

Can I alter a column charset and collation in MS SQL 2005 for a specific column without changing the collation of the entire database. I just need it for one column (or table)

I know this can be done in MySQL with a simple "ALTER TABLE" query, but in MS SQL..?

Regards

/C

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE
    MyTable
ALTER COLUMN
    MyColumn nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The collation can be specified as a part of a varchar data type.